# django csv file upload managing

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, python-3.x

```
def createlist(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        files =  request.FILES['ListFile']
        print(type(files))
        csv_file = csv.DictReader(files)
        for i in csv_file:
            print(i)
    return HttpResponse("ok")
```

This gives

class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'

_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Here i post this file using ajax
js:

```
$('#form1').ajaxForm(function(data) { 
           alert(data) ; 
        });
```

Comment: What does `print([type(x) for x in files.readlines()])` give you?

Comment: @dilbert [<class 'bytes'>, <class 'bytes'>,

Comment: DING, DING, DING, we have a winner!!

Comment: @dilbert any solution to read files as dictreader to get as dictionary

Comment: You need to either a) change `request.FILES['ListFile']` to a non-binary read mode or b) read all of `request.FILES['ListFile']` into an intermediate file-like object. I would recommend a).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using codec.iterdecode, i solved it.I think this is due to python 3.x

```
import codecs

def createlist(request):
    if request.method == "POST":    
        fil =  request.FILES['ListFile']
        csvfile = csv.DictReader(codecs.iterdecode(fil, 'utf-8'))
        for i in csv_file:
            print(i)
    return HttpResponse("ok")
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSV doesn't support UTF8. It needs the file-like object to be encoded. Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729832/proccessing-a-django-uploadedfile-as-utf-8-with-universal-newlines) for more information.

```
import codecs

def createlist(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        utf8_file = codecs.EncodedFile(request.FILES["ListFile"],"utf-8")
        csv_file = csv.DictReader(utf8_file)
        for i in csv_file:
            print(i)
    return HttpResponse("ok")
```

Comment: _csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)