# Django InMemoryUploadedFile with universal line brakes and utf8

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-uploads

In my django application users can upload their csv files to import data into django. It works fine for CLRF unicode files.

But there are two issues:

1. When the file is not encoded with utf8 I keep getting `'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xdc in position 393: invalid continuation byte`. I tried to resolve that by using the following code

   ```
   file = codecs.EncodedFile(request.FILES['import'],"utf-8")  
   dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(file.read(2048))
   file.open() # seek to 0

   reader = csv.reader(file,dialect=dialect)
   ```
2. When the file uses CR Linebreaks they are not recognized or I get: `new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?`. But the `InMemoryUploadedFile` is already an opened file object.

My issue is very similar to this one but the solution mentioned for point 1 didn't work for me (as you can see my code is very similar) and point 2 isn't answered at all:

[Proccessing a Django UploadedFile as UTF-8 with universal newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729832/proccessing-a-django-uploadedfile-as-utf-8-with-universal-newlines)